# How can I build an env file (with $ characters) listing as-is from echo command?

Tags: bash, echo, variable-substitution

I am trying to build a file invoked from a script that echoes what is in quotes to a file - only, the `$` gets omitted.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
echo -e "export ORACLE_BASE=/oracle/APP/grid \n 
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/APP/grid/12.1.0/grid\n
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH\n export ORACLE_SID=+ASM”>/home/oragrid/ASM.env
```

But it doesn't quite `echo` into the file.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `echo -e` in scripts aimed at portability. Use the shell built-in `printf()` which does everything as the former and still remains compliant across shells. For your requirement though, to store a multi-line string without expanding variables prefixed with `$`, use a here-doc

```
cat << 'EOF' > /home/oragrid/ASM.env
export ORACLE_BASE=/oracle/APP/grid
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/APP/grid/12.1.0/grid
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=+ASM
EOF
```

This would keep all the content within `EOF` intact, not expanding the variables inside.